# can't get a token back from epic fhir auth server

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm not getting a token back from my epic app.

I'm calling my app (PFI_app, non-prod. client id: [my_client_id]) from a browser script:

```
FHIR.oauth2.authorize({
    'client_id':[my_client_id],
    'scope':'openid, fhirUser,PATIENT.READ, PATIENT.SEARCH, OBSERVATION.READ, OBSERVATION.SEARCH',
    'redirect_uri':[my_redirect_uri],
    'state':'abc123',
    'aud':'https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/fhir/r4'
});
```

I get prompted to login at signin.epic.com and i use the credentials FHIR (username) and EpicFhir11!(password), which i got from this page: https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=testpatients.

at my redirect url page i use the following to get the access token:

```
FHIR.oauth2.ready()
      .then(function(client){
        myapp.smart = client
        console.log(client);
      })
```

BUT, i keep getting the following error message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
app.html:39   https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token

i get another message saying: URL: https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token
unauthorized_client

this leads me to believe that i logged in with an improper user who isn't authorized.

ultimately, i don't get a token. any idea why? is it because I'm using improper login credentials and therfore that user doesn't have access to get a token.

also, I'm using fhir-client.js not, fhir-client-v2.js, is that a problem?

**UPDATE:**

so I just waited and token issue resolved itself. perhaps there was a time period I had to wait after changing my epic fhir app information at fhir.epic.com. I changed the "Application Audience" from patients to "clinicians and administrative users." I had been logging in to epic when prompted as an admin for many hours before I wrote this post, but I can't think of anything that I changed to my code. I just waited.

now my last remaining problem is that when I try and search for patients from the sandbox with this code:

```
var obs = await fetch(myapp.smart["state"]["serverUrl"]+"/Patient?address=123%20Main%20St.&address-city=Madison&address-postalcode=53703&address-state=Wisconsin&family=Mychart&gender=Female&given=Allison&telecom=608-123-4567",{
          headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json+fhir",
            "Authorization":"Bearer"+myapp.smart["state"]["tokenResponse"]["access_token"]
          }
        }).then(function(data){
          return data;
        });
        
        var response = await obs.json();

        console.log( response );
```

I get another "unauthorized message":

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)   https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4/Patient?address=123%20Main%20St.&address-city=Madison&address-postalcode=53703&address-state=Wisconsin&family=Mychart&gender=Female&given=Allison&telecom=608-123-4567

this is where I got the syntax for structuring this call to the Patient.search resource:

https://fhir.epic.com/Sandbox?api=932

***any ideas why I'm unauthorized to make this call?*** again, I'm logged in using the provider-facing app user credentials listed here: https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=testpatients (username: FHIR)

UPDATE:

so I changed the FHIR.oauth2.ready call to include the request and it worked. I'm not sure why I couldn't include the provided token as a Bearer token in fetch but the following worked:

```
var req = "/Patient?address=123%20Main%20St.&address-city=Madison&address-postalcode=53703&address-state=Wisconsin&family=Mychart&gender=Female&given=Allison&telecom=608-123-4567"

FHIR.oauth2.ready( client => client.request(req) ).then(function(output){
        console.log(output); /* should include search results for the patient */ 
});
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Have you reached out to open@epic.com?

Comment: Additionally, we could use some more details here. I take it you are doing a standalone launch for a provider-facing app...is that correct? And you are successfully obtaining an authorization token from Epic, but your request for an access token is failing, correct? If the latter is true, then the user credentials are correct and there is something likely malformed about your access token request. But, we would need more details like what you are passing and whether you are using client secrets or not.

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie I haven't tried that one, I tried info@. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @ExceptionAl correct, standalone, provider facing. also, you're correct, I'm failing to get an access token (the latter). I just assumed that FHIR.oauth would handle getting the authentication code and exchange it for the auth token ( in this Line FHIR.oauth2.ready().then( ...) ), am I mistaken? I'm not using client secrets, I'm unsure how to do that or where to find that info. also, I'm not passing any other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, I changed the FHIR.oauth2.ready call to include the request and it worked.:

```
var req = "/Patient?address=123%20Main%20St.&address-city=Madison&address-postalcode=53703&address-state=Wisconsin&family=Mychart&gender=Female&given=Allison&telecom=608-123-4567"

FHIR.oauth2.ready( client => client.request(req) ).then(function(output){
        console.log(output); /* should include search results for the patient */ 
});
```

In addition, I had to wait a period of time, possibly due to the fact that I made some changes in my epic fhir app.